# How to improve my body image?

Tags: bodybuilding, bodyweight-exercises, health, body-measurements

My body is like this ever since i lost 36 kg a year ago :
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvIT2Y7GmEM6gTDTJsn5RJDAH5w3
Please , can someone give me some exercises , or any true and tested methode to improve my body in home (since covid 19  is all around us ).

Comment: You really need to focus your question, it's currently too broad. Also, I'm not clicking that link. I'd suggest posting the photos inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too broad to answer but let's start with a 3 day a week full body workout..

Each day do all of these:
1 horizontal pull exercise(rotate horizontal pulls with vertical pulls)
1 horizontal push(rotate chest exercises and shoulder exercises)
1 Quad exercise
1 Hip dominant exercise(rotate hip extension and knee flexion exercises)

your exercises depends on your budget..

No money? Bodyweight exercises

Little money? Resistance bands, super bands, etc.. these go up all the way to 150 and you can combine them to go up to a 1000. You can literally workout your entire body

Some money? Buy a barbell, bench, power rack, and adjustable dumbbell handles that you can add weight yourself to, plus several weight plates. Dumbbells and barbell exercises (also known as dumbbar) are all you need to get built. This is the preferred approach and the most realistic

Lot of money? Invest in a gym room and do whatever you want.

Diet: because you're skinny fat thats a sign that youre insulin resistant, not a good thing!! No matter what you're diet is, whether you're bulking or cutting, get rid of all saturated days, sugars, and junk food. Just eat clean

You cannot do specific exercises to fix belly fat.. mainly because spot reduction, or exercising a part of your body to burn more fat in the part of the body, simply doesn't exist. So cutting calories and junk food are the keys. A good mix of cardio, both high and low intensity such as jogging and jump roping can be added to help lose weight.

Comment: I want mainly to fix my belly shape and around ut , is there more specific exercises for these parts?

Comment: I'll edit my answer

Comment: basically you cannot fix belly shape, areas around it unless you lose fat, which is reducing calories and eating clean food. The belly shape is because it looks to be all unhealthy stomach fat, which might be from insulin resistance which occurs if you eat a lot of sugar. You can workout your body in a way to take attention away from your belly, such as building your chest and shoulders, but this isn't the most efficient way and doesn't solve your problem

Comment: Ok , Thank you very much for your advices